# UML (or other modeling) tool which can create JavaScript, especially Node.js

Tags: javascript, software-development, programming, modeling, uml

What are some tools (or set of tools) out there that can create JavaScript from a diagram such as UML.  This is especially of interest for Node.js but JavaScript in general is of interest too.

Ideally it would also have the ability to create a diagram from Code as well, but that's not a requirement.

The goal is to use it to do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture

UPDATE Jan 9, 2018:
The software should run on Windows and Mac.  Paid is fine, no particular budget as this is for commercial purposes and if a more expensive product saves more money than it costs because it's more effective, then it's easily justified.

Answer (score 1):

You should look to Wikipedia's [List of Unified Modeling Language tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).

You don't specify an o/s, but [StarUML](http://staruml.io/) generates NodeJs (there are more which generate JS) and runs on Windows, macOS & Linux.

You also don't specify whether it should be [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) or if you have a budget (those two things should be specified on every question, else how are we to help you? Garbage in, garbage out).

Star UML costs US $70 for a personal license. If you want a free solution, look further to the Wikipedia page.

And, if you have any special wishes for features, other than just "UML", please state the. The more info that you give us, the better that we can help you.

I hope that this helps. Please let us know, in order to help others who read this question in future.

[image]